# C# Делегаты передача любого количества параметров любого типа

Tags: c#, делегаты

Мне необходимо создать свой делегат (не использовать готовые Action/Func), при этом он должен принимать любое количество параметров, любого типа

```
public delegate void ButtonActionDelegate(params object[] array);
```

Будет ли правильно если я так реализую? И при создании методов, которые я буду передавать в делегат мне указывать тип данных object?
И как именно понять что нужно использовать именно это метод, если я передам несколько?

Comment: В делегат, и в метод на который вы будете получать этот делегат. Параметры должны совпадать.

Comment: Да, так можно делать. Кроме того, можно использовать `IEnumerable<object> values` - это даст возможность использовать любую коллекцию. Можно одновременно иметь два (или больше) делегатов с разными сигнатурами.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25690325/12888024

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отвечает Джон Скит
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25690479/5574962

---

Вы не сможете использовать стандартные `Action` делегаты с `params`, но можно объявить свой собственный:

```
public delegate void ParamsAction(params object[] arguments)
```

Затем

```
// Обратите внимание --- нет params, но могло и быть
public void Foo(object[] args)
{
    // Что угодно
}

...

ParamsAction action = Foo;
action("a", 10, 20, "b");
```

Конечно, вы можете создать `Action<object[]>` для вашего существующего метода, но тогда потеряете поддержку `params`, т.к. он не объявлен в  `Action<T>`. Т.е. для примера:

```
public static void Foo(params object[] x)
{
}

...

Action<object[]> func = Foo;
func("a", 10, 20, "b"); // Нельзя
func(new object[] { "a", 10, 20, "b" }); // Можно
```

И так, если вы вызываете делегат из кода, где хотите использовать `params`, вам необходим делегат, который содержит его в определении (как в начале ответа). Если вы хотите создать делегат, который  принимает просто `object[]`, то можно создать экземпляр `Action<object[]>`
, использующий метод у которого есть `params` в сигнатуре - это просто ключевое слово, не влияет на продуктивность.